# Convert pointcloud to image

Tags: ros, pcl, velodyne-pointcloud, pcl-ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i have a bagfile with velodyne packets in it. I want to convert this point cloud into an image or a range image. Anyone please help me how to convert it.

i went through the documentation in [Tutorials/CloudToImage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage) for converting pointcloud to image.I used the node
"convert_pointcloud_to_image" But when i tried it i get an error :-

Error in converting cloud to image message: No rgb field!!

please help me out with this error.Is there any documentation for converting to range image ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49955/convert-pointcloud-to-image/) by [KARTHIK MURUGAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/3722/karthik-murugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-12-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) on 2015-02-20**:
Followup: is it possible to generate a greyscale image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [pcl::toROSMsg](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.1.0/namespacepcl.html#a31460a4b07150db357c690a8ae27d1e6) documentation:

> Copy the RGB fields of a PointCloud2 msg into sensor_msgs::Image format.

It appears your pointcloud has no RGB data attached to it. How did you record it?

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0